# Find my samsung notification

Tags: notifications

When logging into the "Find My Mobile" website, why do notifications appear on the phone that I am trying to locate? I don't really want someone to know if they steal my phone that I am tracking it.
I have tried turning off notifications for "Find my mobile", but they still appear on the phone. I have a galaxy s8 and s10.
Is there any way around this?

Answer (score 1):

I assume that the notification is shown for legal reasons. In a lot of countries it is illegal to track user positions without their knowledge/approval.

Just an theoretical example: Let us assume there are two Samsung devices on your account, your own device and the device of your partner. Now you are getting jealous and start tracking the movements of your parter's device using the Samsung find my device system. Such usage is illegal in a lot of countries.

In your case you just don't want the notification to be visible on the lock screen. Therefore it should be sufficient to configure the notifications of the Samsung Find my Device service to be not shown on the lock screen.

Comment: Yes, and if your device is stolen there is almost 0 chance you are getting it back